# jquery autocomplete over ajax fails under CakePHP3.x

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, cakephp-3.0

I have a page with the following jQuery snippet:

```
$( "#fuser" ).autocomplete({
    source: "/users/jsonusers",

select: function(event, ui) {
    $("#find").val(ui.item.value);
    return false;
 },
 focus: function(event, ui) {
    $("#find").val(ui.item.label);
    return false;
 }
```

The code at the "source url" looks like this:

```
    $connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');
    $results = $connection->execute($query, ['str' => $find])->fetchAll('assoc');

    $users = [];
    foreach($results as $user){
        $users[] = ['value'=>$user['user_id'], 'label'=>$user['full_name']];
    }

    $this->set(compact('users'));           
//  $this->set('_serialize', 'users'); // this is the correction that works
    $this->set('_serialize', ['users']); // this is Bake's default
```

When I try to use the autocomplete widget, it fails completely.

Looking in my console, I think I know why. It looks like Cake is putting my "keys" ('name' and 'value') into quotes, so the json looks like this:

```
[
        {
            "value": "46",
            "label": "Test User"
        }
]
```

Instead of like this:

```
[
    {
        value:"46",
        label:"Test User"
    }
]
```

So I figured, "just build the damn object yourself manually. Easy to iterate though the array and format the json as desired, no?"

But no, I would be wrong. CakePHP does not allow me to dictate at all how data is transmitted over ajax. I am stuck with Cake's formatting. If I try to make my own json object, it gets mangled with encoding and STILL gets buried as a sub-object regardless.

What am I doing wrong? Or is this just a bug with Cake? If so, is there some workaround? Can I get jQuery autocomplete to work with the json object returned by Cake? Do I need to parse it further in the js?  Sadly, if so, that exceeds my knowledge of using jQuery.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need array like this:

```
[
  {
    value:"46",
    label:"Test User"
  }
]
```

Then you can simply do:

```
$this->set('_serialize', 'users');
```

Instead of:

```
$this->set('_serialize', ['users']);
```

Means just serialize the string not an array.

Comment: That was an unfortunate typo and I appreciate you catching it and helping, but it's not the source of my problem. I corrected my code and post. The generated JSON is still not being parsed by jQuery as it would be if I manually created it and embedded it as a JS var on the page (which I can't do because I need the dynamic full text query on the server and it's a lot of data)

Comment: what if make your source like this /users/jsonusers.json ??

Comment: If you hit your source in url including '.json' you would get exactly the same array you looking for.

Comment: Just to follow up. After correcting the typo (which I've since realized was generated by Cake's own Bake engine, and isn't a typo as much as an inconvenient/undocumented "feature"), as I said, the problem persisted. But later it "magically" went away.  Recalling earlier attempts at debugging were met with frustration when code changes weren't reflected in live tests, I've concluded that even with debug mode set to false, there IS SOME form of caching of ajax requests. I don't know what or how.  But nothing else explains why this failed after making Manohar's suggested edit only to work later.

Comment: So Manohar's suggestion to remove the [braces] DID fix the behavior (although the JSON still has quoted keys, but it works regardless). — Alternatively, another suggestion that I was given at CakePHP's own discussion site — which also worked — would be to simply use die($json) in the controller to output the raw text as desired.